# Python .I need method to use the input of user as variable name

Tags: python

```
#python
    joe=(22,"medical","second class ")
    layla=(23,"medical","third class")

    name_of_employee=input("write the name of employee that you need his information ")

print("")
```

I need  a method when the user input the name as joe the python print his information

Comment: You *don't* need to do that and you *shouldn't*. Instead, use a *container* like a `dict` that maps a `str` to another object, and use that `dict` with the `str` you receive from user input

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary may help you:

```
employees_info = {"joe": (22,"medical","second class "),
                  "layla": (23,"medical","third class")}

name_of_employee=input("write the name of employee that you need his information ")

print(employees_info[name_of_employee])
```